# Need plugin or code for "view site as desktop version" button to responsive Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I need to add a "view site as desktop version" button to my responsive Wordpress site. Mobile user will see the responsive version that has less content by design but Some mobile users prefer the full desktop version.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: I truly believe that would cause an infinite loop as your "desktop version" appears to be responsive so the user would see the same thing. Try changing the viewport or removing media queries on page that they arrive to!

Comment: Sounds logic @papakia. But i have seen that function at some websites. Maybe they have solved it like you suggest. Maybe someone else knows some more solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility for doing this is putting all your `@media` queries in a separate CSS file. When the user opts to see the desktop site, set a cookie and have your site not include that CSS file for users with the cookie set.